# django 4.1 tutorial how to change the link on the admin page header from http://localhost:8000 to http://localhost:8000/polls/

Tags: django

In the Admin pages of the Polls Tutorial there is a link to "View Site" that has the URL http://localhost:8000/ but it should be http://localhost:8000/polls/ to list the polls in the indexView class.

I could not find where to change that View Site link.

Right now with the Polls Tutorial done and all working except this last little bit I want to get it done to use as a reference.

http://localhost:8000 now gives...

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
polls/
admin/
The empty path didn’t match any of these.
```

Comment: You can try to change the link in admin/index.html https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates

Comment: Can you add the general `URLs` file that resides in the same folder as the `settings.py` file and the `URLs` files of all your apps?

Comment: Well I followed the 4.1 tutorial to the letter and polls/templates/polls/index.html and mysite/templates/admin/base_site.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way for me was to change the "View Site" link in the admin header.

go to admin.py and set

```
admin.site.site_url = 'http://localhost:8000/instruction/'
```